# Adding none extjs controls to extjs toolbar menu

Tags: extjs4

Am trying to add a none extjs `element` to a `toolbar` menu items, let's say for example I want to add a jquery ui element to the extjs `menu` items.

Is this possible or doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `jQuery` component as a ExtJS Component and use it inside the toolbar.

This basically involves extending `Ext.Component` and `overriding` the `render` function.

See this [components-section-creating-custom-components](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/components-section-creating-custom-components)